# Docker how do shell functions get installed?

Tags: docker

I have been following [this](http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/06/19/multinode-hadoop-cluster-on-docker/) blog post, and after pulling the Docker image, shell functions are available. [Here](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-ambari/blob/master/ambari-functions) are the functions that get installed. What I don't understand is how do they get installed onto my shell in the first place? They aren't included in the Dockerfile as far I can tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell functions aren't added by the Docker container.  The command

```
curl -Lo .amb j.mp/docker-ambari && . .amb
```

downloads a script from http://j.mp/docker-ambari to a temporary file `.amb` and then executes it.

The j.mp link expands to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sequenceiq/docker-ambari/master/ambari-functions so this is how the shell commands are installed.